# Does the RA and DEC of the sun change with time?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, astronomy, sun

I'm almost certainly misreading this, but it's said that "one of the great advantages of the equatorial system is that the RA and Dec of a star do not change with time, at least over short timescales."

(http://slittlefair.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy115/session2/moreCel/moreCel.html)

My understanding, by the definition of the equatorial system, was that the sun's RA to change by 2 hours every month.

What am I missing?

Comment: Colloquial exclusion of the Sun from the set of stars?

Comment: Of course, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @notovny:

Colloquial exclusion of the Sun from the set of stars?